# Viewing ID of organic group?

Tags: 7, organic-groups

I am trying to display the ID of the group the user is currently viewing. I created a block, and added the following PHP code into it:

```
<?php
$group = og_context();
if ( !empty($group) ) {
   print "$group->nid";
}
?>
```

Problem is, when I run it, I get the following error:

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Any idea why this is happening, and how to fix it? Seems like it should be easy enough of a task.

Comment: <?php print arg(1); ?> if it is a node page...

Comment: Which version of Drupal are you using ?

Comment: I am using Drupal 7.26

Comment: @AnilSagar -- your suggestion worked. Can you please explain how this works? I am not super familiar with PHP. Thanks!

Comment: Each content created using content types in Drupal is a node which will have nid and path node/nid . Groups also nodes.... you can read path arguments using arg function.. so arg(0) is "node" and arg(1) is nid of node... Find more here https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense. Unfortunately, on second thought, I am not sure if it will serve my purpose, because I need to get the ID of the group the node belongs to, not just the ID of the node itself. This will only work on the group page itself. If I create content for the group, that content will then display its own ID.

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23461/how-can-i-get-the-group-id-of-a-node For getting group content group id

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13648/discussion-between-anil-sagar-and-lukas-pleva)

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7 the NID is the group ID so you could just output $node->nid.

Comment: But I need the group ID to be printed on all nodes associated with the group, not just on the group page itself. Apologies if I wasn't clear in my original ask.

Comment: Is it possible for a content entity to be a member of more than one group on your site?

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that `og_context()` doesn't return an object, or the group node - it returns an array of group information.

Basically, using your example code, you want `$group['gid']`, assuming that all of your organic groups are based off of nodes.  If they aren't, you'll want to also look at `$group['group_type']`.  See http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!og!og_context!og_context.module/function/og_context/7 for more information about this function.